Can you put Grace I&W shield HT over existing granular ice shield?
Replacing shingles with metal roof, and putting down Grace I&W shield.  There are 2 rows of existing granular ice shield present that won't come off.  I see references to not going over it with Grace, but not sure how to handle then.  No idea manufacturer of the old stuff.  Any idea best way to handle?
